# udp connection to server

Tags: sockets, templates, connection, udp

I got a template ($request) to send to a server on a udp port.

I compile the $request as:

```
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <srv version="1.0" msg_type="request">
        <header>
            <param name="SN" value="'       . ++$SN . '" />
            <param name="User" value="'     . $api_user . '" />
            <param name="Cmd" value="'      . $Cmd . '" />
        </header>
     <MyCmd>
     </MyCmd>
</srv>';
```

I try then to communicate to the server with:

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n<br />";

//Communication loop
while(1)
{

    if( ! socket_sendto($sock, $input , strlen($request) , 0 , $server , $port))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    //Now receive reply from server and print it
    if(socket_recv ( $sock , $reply , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    echo "Reply : $reply";
}
```

and I get:

Socket created 
Could not send data: [0] Success

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you set your `$input` variable?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'UDP connection'.

Comment: $input should be $request   - Thanks! but did not change the result. It seems I do not get the length of $request

Comment: It seems to loop within if(socket_recv ... I did not realize it before. How can I debug that more? I do not have any means to debug on the server.

Comment: I solved it by breaking out of the loop.